# 'rails server -e development' fails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am following the instructions [here](https://github.com/teambox/teambox/wiki/Installing-locally), to try to install Teambox locally. In the instructions, the following command is to be typed at the CLI:

```
rails server -e development
```

However when I issue that command, I get the following response:

```
root@localhost:/home/oompah/webstuff/teambox# rails server -e development
getopt: invalid option -- 'e'
Terminating...
```

I removed the `e` option, and the command simply seemed to (re)generate the server side files - and prompted me if I wanted to overwrite the existing files.

Needless to say, Teambox is not available on http://localhost:3000 as the documentation suggests - most likely because of the preceding error highlighted above.

BTW, I am running on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?. Is the documentation wrong (outdated), or am I doing something wrong?

**[Edit]**

I forgot to add:

```
root@localhost:/home/oompah/webstuff/teambox# rails --version
getopt: unrecognised option '--version'
Terminating...
```

Which is pretty annoying, since I can't even find out which version it is. Incidentally, I installed rails using:

```
apt-get install rails
```

**[Edit2]**

```
root@localhost:/home/oompah/teambox# gem query | grep rails
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/yard-0.6.4/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": undefined method `overwrite_accessor' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
rails (3.0.3)
rspec-rails (2.3.1)
sprockets-rails (0.0.1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `rails --version`?

Comment: looks like you have rails2 installed, but document you are using describes installation on top on rails3.

Comment: @Andrew Marchal:
root@localhost:/home/oompah/webstuff/rails/teambox# rails --version
getopt: unrecognised option '--version'
Terminating...

Comment: @Koraktor: Please see my updated question (Edit2)

Comment: Seems like your rails installation is kind of broken. What gives `which rails`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the terse (too terse?) doco from the Teambox site.  The command they list will run the stock `rails` binary, *not* the one in the `<teambox install dir>/script/` directory.

e.g.

```
$which rails
/usr/bin/rails.
```

This isn't what you want.

Change your command to:

```
cd <teambox install dir>

script/rails server -e development.
```

This will run their custom rails binary in the script subdir of your teambox install, not the stock rails binary on your path :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rails server --environment development
```